# Sync array values across all related array keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP array with the following data

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4095
            [2] => 651
        )

    [4095] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [651] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4432
        )

    [4432] => Array
        (
            [0] => 651
        )
    [92] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
        )
)
```

The above array has keys as `student_id` and the values are also `student_id` creating a circular relation. What I am trying to achieve is all the `student_id` has the same set of `student_id` values. Basically if `student_id` `3` is related to `4095`, `4432` & `651`, then, in turn, each of these values has to have `3` among them including other `student_id` from `3`. The below output demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4095
            [1] => 4432
            [2] => 651
        )

    [4095] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4432
            [2] => 651
        )

    [651] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4432
            [2] => 4095
        )

    [4432] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4095
            [2] => 651
        )
    [92] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
        )
    [45] => Array
        (
            [0] => 92
        )
)
```

#### Explanation of output

The array keys `3`, `4095`, `651` & `4432` are related to each other either directly or via a common relation (indirect), so will have common set of values (siblings). The key `92` in input array has a value (sibling) of `45`, so in a resultant array, a new key `45` will be added to array with the inverse relation as well.

#### What I have tried so far

I have tried to do it with this code

```
$syncedSiblings = [];
        foreach ($studentsWithSiblings as $sid => $siblings) {
            $all = map_assoc(array_merge([$sid], array_keys($siblings)));
            foreach ($all as $studentId) {
                if (isset($syncedSiblings[$studentId])) {
                    $old = $syncedSiblings[$studentId];
                    $syncedSiblings[$studentId] = array_unique(array_merge($old, array_except($all, $studentId)));
                } else {
                    $syncedSiblings[$studentId] = array_unique(array_except($all, $studentId));
                }
            }
        }
```

Where `$studentsWithSiblings` has the above array & `array_except` returns array without the passed values as second argument.

This is the output I am getting right now

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4095
            [1] => 651
        )

    [4095] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 651
        )

    [651] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4095
            [2] => 4432
        )

    [4432] => Array
        (
            [0] => 651
        )
    [92] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
        )

)
```

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: And what have you done till this moment? You need to show your array as it is.

Comment: what is `map_assoc()`?

Comment: `map_assoc()` converts indexed array into associative array

Comment: @AksenP Updated the question with my solution that I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, then this possible to achieve with recursion:

```
function getChildren($ind_ar, $prev_ar, $data, $rem){

    $tmp = [];
    $mark = 0;
    foreach($ind_ar as $ind){

        foreach($data[$ind] as $new_val){

            if(!in_array($new_val,$prev_ar) && $new_val != $ind && $new_val != $rem){

                $mark = 1;
                $tmp[] = $new_val;
            }

            foreach($data[$new_val] as $new){
                if(!in_array($new,$prev_ar) && $new != $ind && $new != $rem){

                    $mark = 1;
                    $tmp[] = $new;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $res_ar = $prev_ar;

    if(!empty($tmp)) $res_ar = array_unique(array_merge($tmp,$prev_ar));  
    if($mark) $res_ar = getChildren($tmp,$res_ar,$data, $rem);   

    return $res_ar;
}
```

You can use this function in this way:

```
$data = array( 3 => [4095, 651], 4095 => [3], 651 => [4432], 4432 => [3, 651], 92 => [45], 45 => [92], );

foreach($data as $in => &$data_val) { 
    $data_val = getChildren([$in],$data_val,$data, $in);
    sort($data_val);
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hBs85)**

Output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 651
            [1] => 4095
            [2] => 4432
        )

    [4095] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 651
            [2] => 4432
        )

    [651] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4095
            [2] => 4432
        )

    [4432] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 651
            [2] => 4095
        )

    [92] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [0] => 92
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked for the example array, but I think I have confused you with my example. Please check the updated example. Also my actual array is large and php runs out of allocated memory of 512M using this code. Here is the actual array https://pastebin.com/DhmCRFnn

Comment: @Ehs4n, in fact, it works in my project. Yes, it's a big amount of data, but I haven't used extending of allocated memory at all. You can try to use `ini_set("max_execution_time", "0");
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");`

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't help with what I am trying to achieve. Kindly check my modified example.

Comment: @Ehs4n, well, ok, fine. I don't see your mentioned relations as if student_id 3 is related to 4095, 4432 & 651. I see only 4095 and 651. Your example can't be logically processed

Comment: Basically, the problem is student `3` is related to say, `4` & `5` and `4` in turn is related to `6` & `6` related to `7`. What i want is an array where `3` has values of `[4, 5, 6, 7]` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Two nested loops over the data. If the keys are different, then check if the key of the inner loop is already contained in the data array of the outer key element - if not, add it.

```
$data = json_decode('{"3":{"0":4095,"2":651},"4095":[3],"651":[4432],"4432":{"1":651}}', true);

foreach($data as $key_outer => $val_outer) {
  foreach($data as $key_inner => $val_inner) {  
    if($key_outer != $key_inner && !in_array($key_inner, $data[$key_outer])) {
      $data[$key_outer][] = $key_inner;
    }
  }
}

var_dump($data);
```

This gets you

```
array (size=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 4095
      2 => int 651
      3 => int 4432
  4095 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 651
      2 => int 4432
  651 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 4432
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 4095
  4432 => 
    array (size=3)
      1 => int 651
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4095
```

I am assuming a specific order of the elements in those sub-items is not actually required. If it is, then please sort them yourself as desired afterwards or in between (depending on what exactly you need, f.e. `sort($data[$key_outer]);` after the inner loop would get you the IDs in all sub-arrays sorted ascending.)

Comment: Thank you. It worked for the example array, but my actual array is large and php runs out of allocated memory of 512M using this code. Here is the actual array https://pastebin.com/DhmCRFnn

Also I want the values clubbed together, only for those keys which are in some way related to each other and not for all the keys.

Comment: I have edited my sample arrays a little bit to explain it further.